# Как отловить нажатие двух клавиш одновременно на javascript?

Tags: javascript keydown

`(ctrl|shift|alt)Key` не предлагать.

В идеале, конечно, узнать бы без обработчика, в произвольном месте кода (в моем случае из `requestAnimationframe`), какие клавиши в данный момент нажаты. Но подойдет и, гм, обработчик подобного события, если это вообще реализуемо. Единственное, что мне пришло в голову - это в onkeydown собирать в очередь нажатые клавиши, а в `requestAnimationframe` эту очередь разбирать.

Но если одна клавиша зажата, то нажатие других keydown не ловит. (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте.

```
var keys = [];
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var code = e.which;
    if (keys.indexOf(code)<0){
        keys.push(code);
    }
    console.log(keys);
});

$(document).keyup(function(e){
  keys.splice(keys.indexOf(e.which),1);
  console.log(keys);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o6rc1fct/
ЗЫ И букв получилось меньше, чем в вопросе.

Comment: А можно всё тоже самое,но без jQuery?

Comment: @Darth, можно. Может, сами попробуете?

Comment: Да,спасибо!
А почему вот такая конструкция - 
document.onkeydown=function(e){сonsole.log(e.keyCode);}
В консоли печатает код только той клавиши,которая зажата,а вторую если в это время нажать - в логе нету? Если б не это досадное обстоятельство,я бы сам справился

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o6rc1fct/1/ так работает.